# Jenkins hosted on tomcat with Nginx in front

Tags: nginx, jenkins, tomcat8

I'm working on setting up Jenkins on tomcat with nginx in front of tomcat.
Our Idea is that once we login in Jenkins, Instead of going to Jenkins Home page , we should get re-directed to Plugin installed on Jenkins. Plugin

Ports :-
Nginx :- 80
Tomcat :- 8080

My nginx configuration look like below :-

```
upstream tomcat {
server <IPADDR>:8080 weight=100 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=5;
}
server {
 listen          80;
server_name    _;
root            /usr/local/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/jenkins;
        location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://<IPADDR>/jenkins;
         rewrite ^/jenkins/(.*)$ http://<IPADDR>/jenkins/<Plugin> permanent;
  }
}
```

After I launch http:/IPADDR/jenkins, we get the jenkins login page and after logging , we go to http:/IPADDR/jenkins/Plugin as expected.

However , when we logout of Jenkins, the Url in browser is http:/IPADDR:8080/jenkins and logging into this Url takes me to Jenkins home page, which i want to restrict.

I assume that i need to make some changes in tomcat's server.xml for achieving this.
i tried below setting in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
            proxyPort="80"
            scheme="http"/>
```

But , the setup isn't working.
Can someone plz help me identify the mistake i'm making.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you found any solution for this